# VBA - listview sort by drag and drop

Tags: vba, listview, drag-and-drop, drag

I'm trying to implement drag and drop sorting in listview on my vba form. I found many solutions for vb forms. But they doesn't work in vba. I also found one article for vba and it almost works. But problem is that when I drag item my cursor doesn't highlight other items when mouseover. It only highlight 1st line when I drag item below last line. Here is [2 screenshots](http://puu.sh/owcCq/6a26817285.jpg) for better explanation. And here is code:

```
Public Sub LVDragDropSingle(ByRef lvList As ListView, ByVal x As Single, 

ByVal y As Single)
'Item being dropped
Dim objDrag As ListItem
'Item being dropped on
Dim objDrop As ListItem
'Item being readded to the list
Dim objNew As ListItem
'Subitem reference in dropped item
Dim objSub As ListSubItem
'Drop position
Dim intIndex As Integer

'Retrieve the original items
Set objDrop = lvList.HitTest(x, y)
Set objDrag = lvList.SelectedItem
If (objDrop Is Nothing) Or (objDrag Is Nothing) Then
    Set lvList.DropHighlight = Nothing
    Set objDrop = Nothing
    Set objDrag = Nothing
    Exit Sub
End If

'Retrieve the drop position
intIndex = objDrop.Index

'Remove the dragged item
lvList.ListItems.Remove objDrag.Index

'Add it back into the dropped position
Set objNew = lvList.ListItems.Add(intIndex, objDrag.key, objDrag.Text, objDrag.Icon, objDrag.SmallIcon)

'Copy the original subitems to the new item
If objDrag.ListSubItems.Count > 0 Then
    For Each objSub In objDrag.ListSubItems
        objNew.ListSubItems.Add objSub.Index, objSub.key, objSub.Text, objSub.ReportIcon, objSub.ToolTipText
    Next
End If

'Reselect the item
objNew.Selected = True

'Destroy all objects
Set objNew = Nothing
Set objDrag = Nothing
Set objDrop = Nothing
Set lvList.DropHighlight = Nothing

End Sub
```

And 2 subs for userform:

```
Private Sub ListView1_OLEDragOver(Data As MSComctlLib.DataObject, Effect As Long, Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, x As Single, y As Single, State As Integer)

    Set ListView1.DropHighlight = ListView1.HitTest(x, y)

End Sub

Private Sub ListView1_OLEDragDrop(Data As MSComctlLib.DataObject, Effect As Long, Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, x As Single, y As Single)

    Call LVDragDropSingle(ListView1, x, y)

End Sub
```

This article i found has some explanation. Too bad I can't post link to it because I'm not allowed to post more than one link.

Answer (score 0):

I've spent several days trying to figure out whats wrong and I think problem is in that particular implementation of listview. Seems that HitTest(x, y) method of this listview simply isn't working properly. After 2 days of trial and error i've come to this solution:

```
Public Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dx As Long, ByVal dy As Long, ByVal cButtons As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)  
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)  
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2  
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4  

Public LstItmObj As ListItem  
Public swapNeeded As Boolean 'swap mode  

Private Sub SingleClick()  
  mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0  
  mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0  
End Sub  

'set no-swap mode until drag started  
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()  
    swapNeeded = False     
End Sub  

'when drag started we save current selected row as we will swap it with next selected row  
Private Sub ListView1_OLEStartDrag(Data As MSComctlLib.DataObject, AllowedEffects As Long)  
    Set LstItmObj = UF2.ListView1.SelectedItem  
End Sub  

'when drop occurs we make mouseclick to select next item and then set swap mode on  
Private Sub ListView1_OLEDragDrop(Data As MSComctlLib.DataObject, Effect As Long, Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, x As Single, y As Single)  
'that click will occur only after end of this Sub, that's why we can't make rows swaping here  
    Call SingleClick  
    swapNeeded = True  

End Sub  

'this Sub starts after OLEDragDrop ends so new row is already selected and old row is already saved to LstItmObj so here we just need to swap those two rows  
Private Sub ListView1_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal x As stdole.OLE_XPOS_PIXELS, ByVal y As stdole.OLE_YPOS_PIXELS)  
    If (swapNeeded) Then  
        Sleep 30  
        Dim insertedList As ListItem  
        Dim selectedIndex As Integer  
        Dim newListSubItemObj As ListSubItem  

        selectedIndex = UF2.ListView1.SelectedItem.Index  
        UF2.ListView1.ListItems.Remove LstItmObj.Index  

        Set insertedList = UF2.ListView1.ListItems.Add(selectedIndex, LstItmObj.key, LstItmObj.Text, LstItmObj.Icon, LstItmObj.SmallIcon)  
        For Each newListSubItemObj In LstItmObj.ListSubItems  
                insertedList.ListSubItems.Add newListSubItemObj.Index, newListSubItemObj.key, newListSubItemObj.Text, newListSubItemObj.ReportIcon, newListSubItemObj.ToolTipText  
        Next newListSubItemObj 'swap mode off again  
        swapNeeded = False  
        Set UF2.ListView1.SelectedItem = UF2.ListView1.ListItems.Item(selectedIndex)  
    End If  

End Sub
```