# Excel pixels not proportional to points

Tags: excel, vba

I've noticed that (by changing column width) that the column width measured in points is not proportional to the pixel size. For example, at 21.44 points the pixel width of a column is 200. But at 20 pixels the width becomes 1.44 points, not the expected 2.14 points.

This is very confusing as I'm trying to write a code in VBA which will divide a particular size in 'n' different columns of equal size. Can anyone explain this abnormality? How can I write a code to divide the width (since the parameters for the column width are in points)?

Thanks

Comment: There is a VBA function `PointsToScreenPixelsX`  and  `PointsToScreenPixelsY` But we have  some doubt about it's accuracy. May please refer to [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52704803/listview-control-drag-and-drop/52916524#52916524)

Comment: How are you setting and determining the column width?

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld I'm using the tool provided in Excel, where we select the column and then drag to increase/decrease the column width, to determine the column width both in points and pixels.

Comment: That number is not the number of points.  Rather it is the number of characters of the normal font for your machine that will fit into a column, rounded to something that will not result in a fractional number of pixels.

Answer (score 0):

So I just was trying things and stumbled across this. 
Maybe the numbers are off from a "true" width. If the theory is correct, then there must exist such an offset.
(21.44 + x) = 10 (1.44 + x) 
x = 0.7822 
Now let's see if this offset works for other some other lengths. For 80 pixels, the length mentioned by MS Excel is 8.11 points. Thus the true length is 8.89. The true length of a column with a width 20 pixels is 1.44 + 0.7822 = 2.222. Note that 2.222 * 4 = 8.89 approx. And this works for some other numbers as well, so I guess the theory should be correct.

Thus to answer the question, add the offset 0.7822 to the observed column width that you need to divide. Then divide it by 'n'. Subtract the offset to obtain the length 'x'. Then use the command Columns(var).ColumnWidth = x for each of the n columns